# Help Identifying Time Series Model From ACF and PACF graphs

Tags: time-series

I have a dataset of the popularity of a certain word on the internet, and they are weekly counts from 2010-09-05 to 2015-09-27 and has an upward trend. I'm having a hard time identifying the model from its graphs, and I would love some help to interpret its ACF and PACF models. Thanks in advance!

[image: ACF Plot]

[image: PACF Plot]